# How do i know if the headerRight button has been pressed?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

I want to know if the `headerRight` button has been pressed.

`_layout.js`

```js
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import { useCallback } from "react";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import { COLORS } from "../constants/colors";
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";
import NewMeal from "./newmeal";

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

const Layout = () => {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    SFProDisplay: require('../assets/fonts/SF-Pro-Display-Black.otf')
  })

  const onLayoutRoutView = useCallback(async () => {
    if(fontsLoaded) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded]);

  if(!fontsLoaded) return null;

  return (
    <Stack onLayout={onLayoutRoutView} >
      <Stack.Screen 
        // Code
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
         // Code
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
        name="newmeal"
        options={{
          presentation: 'modal',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: COLORS.box1,
          },
          headerTitleStyle: {
            color: "#FFF"
          },
          headerTitle: "New meal",
          // WANT TO KNOW IF THIS HEADER RIGHT HAS BEEN PRESSED
          headerRight: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={{ color: COLORS.blue, fontSize: 17, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Done</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ),
          headerLeft: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={{ color: COLORS.blue, fontSize: 17  }}>Cancel</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )
        }}
      />
    </Stack>
  )
}

export default Layout;
```

`newmeal.js`

```js
import { SafeAreaView, View } from "react-native"
import { COLORS } from "../constants/colors";

const NewMeal = () => {

  return(
    <SafeAreaView style={{ 
      flex: 1, 
      backgroundColor: COLORS.background,
    }}>
      // WANT TO KNOW HERE IF HEADER RIGHT HAS BEEN PRESSED
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}

export default NewMeal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [setOptions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#setoptions) to update the header buttons from a screen.

```
const NewMeal = ({navigation}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { /* TODO */ }}>
          <Text style={{ ... }}>
            Done
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    });
  }, [navigation]);

...
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your response, I have tried it, but I get an error saying Cannot read properties 'setOptions' of undefined which probably refers to the navigation variable not being passed down to the NewMeal component.

Comment: Fixed it by adding `const navigation = useNavigation()`
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/